# NSArray data in UILabel

Tags: cocoa, nsarray, uilabel

I am trying to put NSArray data by([array valueForKey:@"value_name"]) in uilabel it throws exception.

Regards,
sathish

Answer (score 0, accepted):

How are you assigning this to the UILabel?

You should be doing something like:

```
myLabel.text = [myArray objectAtIndex:0];
```

If you want to retrieve it using the valueForKey method then a variable type such as NSDictionary maybe a better match for it...